# char* and boolean TRUE FALSE in C

Tags: c, char, boolean, char-pointer

I have a piece of legacy code that has got `char*` function arguments which are used for if-then-else logical flow. For example:

```
void myFunc(char *f_reset) {

     .....
     .....
     if(*f_reset) {// do this;}
     else {// do that;}

}
```

suppose I am calling `myFunc(char *f_reset)` from `main()`

```
 void main(void) {
     char r = 0;
     char *f_reset = &r;

     *f_reset = 0;

     myFunc(f_reset);  // Debug and enter this function

  }
```

When I try to enter the function call, I find out that `*f_reset` is never evaluated as `0` i.e. false - it is always true because of some garbage `-8342345825` or something like that.

The reason it is using `char*` is probably because in the old days boolean took more memory than char *? Some stuff I read in the past in Stackoverflow posts.

Could someone give me a dummy's guide for the relationship between `char*` and logical true false?

Comment: Zero literal '0' does not evaluate to zero/false?

Comment: Try `'\0'`, or simply `0`.

Comment: @Shaggi         no it doesn't. I have used 'H', 'L', 'h', 'l', but nothing. If you write a quick small program with an if-then-else based on a `char *` and debug it, it will show you the ascii number, not what you want. Frustrating isn't it?

Comment: @WhozCraig      I am sure 0 doesn't work. I am dead sure.

Comment: Well, then you're wrong as well as dead-sure. `char ar[2], *p = ar; *p = 0; if (*p){} else{}` will *not* execute the if-block. `*p` equates to false. Anything besides a full-zero octet equates to true. Perhaps posting a *real* sample that *compiles* and demonstrates your problem may shed some light?

Comment: @hagubear I know, i pointed it out to the op.. maybe not in a obvious way

Comment: @hagubear is the purpose of the boolean evaluation to see if the first octet in the data addressed by the passed-in parameter non-zero? if it is, then you're doing it right. If it isn't then you need to explain what you *do* want clearer. as posted now, it is correct to check the first `char` of the memory addressed by `f_reset`, and if it is non-zero, the if-block executes. If all you want to do is pass a boolean flag, is there a reason you're passing by address? A by-value parameter (`int` for example) seems it would be a much better fit.

Comment: WhozCraig       if you pass `*p` as an pointer argument now in a function, you will see that the `*p` will be evaluated as -823423847234 or some big horrible number which is logical TRUE and my reset will always be TRUE! which is not right! And yes, I am using `char *` because it is from legacy code written about 15 years ago. I feel ashamed to use char * for logical. Boolean is the best fit for it.

Comment: You better look again. that big hairy value you're talking about is not `*p`, its **`p`**. Its the address held *in* the pointer variable. Dereferencing that address in your `if` condition will give you the `char` value you're looking for. As written you're code will execute the `else` block in `myFunc`.

Comment: @WhozCraig      I know what I mean.... *p dereference it to the value and p means the address where the value is located. if(*p) means if the value addressed by p is a logical true or 1. My understanding of pointer referencing and dereferencing is not flawed!

Comment: [**See It Live**](http://ideone.com/tAG13M). Apparently they are. Unless you're on a system where `char` is 32bit/64bit, your observation of the value of your dereferenced `char *` is lacking something. *What is the problem*??? If that `char` at that address evals non-zero, the `if` block fires, otherwise the `else` block fires.

Answer (score 1):

In **C** there is not the boolean type. The `if` statment evaluete only intergers, so integer value 0 is false, anything else is true. The `char` type can be used as 8bit integer.

The char value:

```
char var = '0';
```

correspond to the integer value `48` (see an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)) and not the integer value 0.

In your example you have a char pointer. But in your if statment your are not evaluating the pointer, but its value; so, *f_reset must be `0` (integer) to be evaluated as false.

```
char var = 0;

...
myFunc(&var);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
void myFunc(char *);
int main()
{
char r = FALSE;
char *f_reset = &r;



myFunc(f_reset);  // Debug and enter this function

}

void myFunc(char *f_reset)

{
if(*f_reset)
printf("true");
else
printf("false");

}
```

Comment: @hugbear You can use this piece of code for sake of simplicity if you want to use boolean as char pointer.Assigning r=TRUE evaluates to true and vice versa

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char *x;
char a=0;
x=&a;

if(*x)
printf("true");
else
printf("false");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try this piece of code n you will get output as false. However assigning a='0'  will give the output as true because it will be converted to its ascii value.

Comment: `@Sarwan`  I know, but if you then pass `*x` to a function, it still evaluates as TRUE, I want it to be false.

Comment: @hagubear what does "pass \*x" to a function it still evaluates as TRUE *mean* ? As I said before, your posted code doesn't even *compile* and isn't even valid C. If you posted a functioning-but-failing example, often called an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org), in your question, along with what you *want* to happen but isn't inline with the code (in comments ideally), it will be *much* easier to understand your goal and why you're not reaching it.

Comment: @WhozCraig        The code snippet is now updated. and my code compiles fine. What I want is a solution how I can correctly use logical true/false using char* in C code.

Comment: @hagubear its looks good. the `f_reset` variable in `main` is somewhat pointless, as you could just pass `&r` and be done with it.  I.e. `char r = 0; myFunc(&r);` But as-written, it should do what you want, in this case the `if (*f_reset)` should eval to false, and the else-block should hit.